# G++ linking with libpng

Tags: macos, g++, macports, libpng

I'm trying to do some image processing using C++. I'm currently using OS X 10.7 and writing my code simply using a makefile and the terminal. I've used macports to install libpng but I still can't link with it.

```
g++ main.cpp -llibpng -O2 -o ImageManipulator

g++ main.cpp -lpng -O2 -o ImageManipulator
```

both fail with:

```
ld: library not found for -lpng
```

and

```
ld: library not found for -llibpng
```

does anyone know how to call g++ for this on OS X?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont think macports does add its lib directory to the default path searched by gcc. Try

```
g++ main.cpp -L/opt/local/lib -lpng -O2 -o ImageManipulator
```

Comment: this worked but the actual filename is libpng.a, libpng.dylib and libpng.la. why does passing -lpng work? shouldn't it be -llibpng?

Comment: Well on *nix like systems it is known (im not sure if it is actually standardized somewhere, but it is actually a fact on all *nixoid systems) that a library is called libXXX, so passing -lpng will evaluate to "link with libpng.a (or dylib, so or whatever)". The only not playing candidate is Windows, where libraries are usually named like XXXlib.lib or XXX.lib :-) If you passed -llibpng, that would evaluate to "link with liblibpng and thus it would not work...

Comment: hence why i just don't use windows for these types of things lol. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use the -L/path/to/library_directory to have g++ know where to find libpng (I have forgotten where mac ports installs the libraries).

Answer (score 0):

Got this error trying to install a gem (Mac OSX / Homebrew).  Fixed by running `brew update && brew install libpng && brew link libpng --force`